# How to Make Absolute Element Clickable?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have some code using [quaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/live_w_locator.html) and overtop the div that will display the camera feed I want to put an "X" when clicked it would stop the library and then go back to the original screen.

I have this code

```js
$('.fa-times-circle').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#cameras {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: visible;
}

.fa-times-circle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select id="cameras">
    <option value="">Select a Camera</option>
  </select>
  <i id="close-camera" class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```

Yet when I click on the "X" nothing happens. It seems like is doing the click on the "container" div. How can I get it to click on the right one?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with pointer-events: none?!

Comment: don't think so, I tried with an without it. Without it is even worse as my selectbox is not even clickable

Comment: I can’t say for sure - *remove `pointer-events: none`* because I don’t see your complete code. But the fact that `pointer-events: none` cancels the behavior of all scenarios - I can say with confidence.

Comment: Use `pointer-events: all;` instead of `pointer-events: visible`, I can't run the snippet btw.

Comment: @HagaiWild, Because `#container` specifies `display: none`, so you can't see the content.

Comment: I have code that hides/shows the container. I think I got it, I think I needed to add 1 more "    pointer-events: visible; to the "X"

Comment: pointer-events: visible` is only valid for SVG elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events